# Preload association table data

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a schema model that look like this.

```
USER => MEETING <= PROJECT
uuid | user_uuid  | 
     | project_id |  id
          hour
```

I want to render in json, an object like this:

```
{
  uuid:"",
  first_name:"",
  project: [
    {
      name:""
      meeting: [
         hour:""
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So a single user has many (many_to_many in this case) project and a project has many (many_to_many also) user.

I also added a relation between project and meeting, because i want to render the meeting data inside the project, my 'project' schema relation:

```
many_to_many :user, User, join_through: Meeting, join_keys: 
[project_id: :id, user_uuid: :uuid]
has_many :meeting, Meeting
```

**The problem is that when I preload my data I get the correct project for the user but I get all the meeting for the project even if the user is not part of it.**

I know where the problem is coming from, since i'm preloading the meeting through the project, ecto doesn't care about the user uuid, it's only looking at the project id and therefore it's loading all the meeting.

I preload my data like this:

```
Repo.all(User)
|> Repo.preload(project: :meeting)
```

How can I preload all the user with all their project and have all the meeting for this project associated with the user ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing condition

```
def with_project_meetings(query) do
  from u in query,
      join: p in assoc(u, :projects),
      join: m in assoc(u, :meetings), on: m.user_uuid == u.uuid,
      preload: [projects: {p, meetings: m}]
end

User |> with_project_meetings |> Repo.all
```

Refer : https://elixirforum.com/t/nested-preload-with-condition/5605/5

Comment: I tried doing something similar but it doesn't change my result.          
query =
        from u in User,
        join: p in assoc(u, :project),
        join: m in assoc(u, :meeting), on: u.uuid == m.user_uuid,
        preload: [projects: {p, meeting: m}]
    
    query |> Repo.all, i also had to add has_many meeting in my user because it was saying that the meeting association didn't existed